# The number of paths on a graph of a fixed length w/o repeatings

Tags: graph-theory

Sorry for bad English.

Consider a graph $G$ with the adjacency matrix $A$. I know that the number of paths of the length $n$ is the sum of elements $A^n$.

But what if we can't walk through a vertex more than one times?

Comment: It that would be as simple as some modified $A^n$, then you would solve [Hamiltonian path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) problem in polynomial time. Of course, we don't know whether $P = NP$ or not, but I strongly suspect, that your formula to be easily provable, will have to include (somewhere, maybe indirectly) exponential number of operations, e.g. $2^n$ additions, multiplications, assignments, whatever.

Comment: @dtldarek: Isn't $A^n$ exponential in $n$?

Comment: @Raskolnikov In terms of number of operations, *no*. E.g. $a^{12} = a\cdot a \cdot a \cdot \ldots \cdot a$ which uses only linear number of multiplications. Moreover, if you rearrange it smartly (that is via [Horner's scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner's_method)) you can make it even logarithimc in $n$, e.g. $a^{12} = ((a^2\cdot a)^2)^2$.

Comment: @dtldarek: Yes, but that only computes how many paths of length $n$ there are. Searching those paths for Hamiltonian ones means searching through an exponentially growing number of paths, regardless of how fast that number can be computed.

Comment: @Raskolnikov An oracle that calculates the number of paths of length $|V|$ that doesn't go twice through any vertex is enough to solve Hamiltonian path problem. Moreover, even if the original problem is of the form "is there a Hamiltonian path of length $k$", it is easy to compute the path itself – just remove any unnecessary edges until a single path remains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a simple expression involving the adjacency matrix for the number of simple (i.e. self-avoiding) paths in an arbitrary graph, but there is an algorithm.

Googling "adjacency matrix number of paths" turned up [this SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1077992/powers-of-adjacency-matrix-doesnt-seem-to-correspond-to-observed-number-of-path) which points out (with a nice example) that powers of the adjacency matrix count the number of *walks* of length $n$, not paths.  That fact also turned up in [this wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix#Matrix_powers).  These walks allow a vertex to be visited more than once, so it's unlikely they can help you to count simple paths.

The paper [Self-Avoiding Paths and the Adjacency Matrix of a Graph - J. Ponstein](http://www.yaroslavvb.com/papers/ponstein-self.pdf) contains an algorithm on pages 9-10 which counts all simple paths in an arbitrary graph.

**Edit**: The good news is explicit formulae for the paths of length $n$ exist, the bad news is the number of terms in the formulae grow exponentially with $n$!

The paper [On the determination of redundancies in sociometric chains - Ross, Ian C.; Harary, Frank](http://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/handle/2027.42/45690) counts the number of 'redundant paths' (i.e. non-simple paths, walks of length $n$ where a vertex is visited more than once).

The English language [powerpoint slideshow](http://mmcp2009.jinr.ru/pdf/3%20-%20S.N.Perepechko,%20A.N.Voropaev%20-%20The%20Number%20of%20Fixed%20Length%20Cycles%20in%20an%20Undirected%20Graph%20Explicit%20Formula%20in%20Case%20of%20Small%20Lengths.pdf) of the Russian language paper "The number of fixed length cycles in an undirected graph. Explicit formulae in case of small lengths" by S. N. Perepechko & A. N. Voropaev contains formula for path lengths 2-5 using the Ross & Harary method.  I reproduce, for your delectation or horror, 2 of the 17476 terms from the path length 10 formula ($\times$ is element-wise matrix multiplication, $\cdot$ is ordinary matrix multiplication):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[**This is a counter-example to wece's answer, posted only as an answer because it's too long for a comment.**]

wece's method is **only** correct for $A_2$. Counterexample: Let $A=\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}0&1&0&0&0\\1&0&1&0&0\\0&1&0&1&0\\0&0&1&0&1\\0&0&0&1&0\end{array}\right]$ representing a chain of 5 vertices connected by 4 edges. $A_1=A-diag(A)=A$.

$A_2=A\otimes A_1 =\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}1&0&1&0&0\\0&2&0&1&0\\1&0&2&0&1\\0&1&0&2&0\\0&0&1&0&1\end{array}\right]$.

In $A_2$ we see all the paths of length 2, the diagonal representing forbidden paths of length 2 from each vertex back to itself, the off-diagonal entries representing the 8 paths of length 2 (path from $a \rightarrow b$ distinct from $b \rightarrow a$). Then

$A_3 = A \otimes A_2 = \left[\begin{array}{ccccc}0&1&0&0&0\\1&0&1&0&0\\0&1&0&1&0\\0&0&1&0&1\\0&0&0&1&0\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0\\1&0&0&0&1\\0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{ccccc}0&0&0&1&0\\1&0&1&0&1\\0&1&0&1&0\\1&0&1&0&1\\0&1&0&0&0\end{array}\right]$,

which according to wece's method represents 10 paths of length 3, when there should be 3 such paths.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A\otimes B$ be defined as the product of matrices where you removed the diagonal i.e.:
$$A\otimes B=(A-diag(A))\times(B-diag(B))$$
Let $A_1=A$ and $A_n=A\otimes A_{n-1}$.

The number of paths of the length n without going through a vertex more than one times is equal to the sum of elements of $A_n$.

Comment: See the **counter-example** in my answer.