# How many paths possible in a 3x3 matrix shaped graph, visiting n nodes?

Tags: graph-theory

Let every element of 3x3 matrix be a node of a graph, and every node has undirected edges to neighbor nodes, vertical, horizontal and diagonal. Nodes can be visited at most one time.

Given n, which is number the of nodes should be visited, how many different paths are there?

For example, how many paths are there visiting 4 and at most 4 nodes?

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299300/the-number-of-paths-on-a-graph-of-a-fixed-length-w-o-repeatings) asks the same question about an arbitrary graph.  I've just posted a counter-example there to the single proposed answer.

Comment: @Frentos Good reference. I remember that adjacency matrices were helping in path calculations from linear algebra classes, but I don't remember how. If you can point a page where its explained I would appreciate it.

Comment: @Frentos I couldn't understand the relation of these two questions. Look, I'm not a mathematician :) If you would explain me your solution in this topic clearly, that would really be helpful, and I don't think it will be a duplicate. Solutions can be same, but the problems are different.

Comment: To make the graph description clearer, are you talking about the graph of king moves on a $3\times3$ chessboard?

Comment: Sorry, I managed to put a link in to the wrong question - guess I was panicking about the duplicate answer comment I got!  My suggested solution is to use the algorithm described in the paper I referenced.

Comment: Yes. Vertical, horizontal and diagonal by one. It's a king move.

Answer (score 1):

As per my answer in [this earlier question about simple paths in arbitrary graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299300/the-number-of-paths-on-a-graph-of-a-fixed-length-w-o-repeatings), there are formulae, but they are impractical (and entertainingly frightening) for anything but very small values of $n$.

The paper [Self-Avoiding Paths and the Adjacency Matrix of a Graph - J. Ponstein](http://www.yaroslavvb.com/papers/ponstein-self.pdf) contains an algorithm on pages 9-10 which counts all simple paths in an arbitrary graph. It gives totals for each path length.

Comment: Edited to refer to other problem but keep key information here.

Comment: Thank you for information. I'm going to read them asap.